# Campagnolo Record C9 / Shimano CS-HG200-9 incompatibility

Tags: chain, shimano, cassette, campagnolo, groupsets

I drive cheap Shimano cassettes together with Campagnolo Record C9 chains. Yesterday I installed a new C9 and a CS-HG200-9. But the chain sort of slips over the sprockets, not unlike really worn parts, but exactly once per revolution and under all loads. Has anyone else experience with this particular setup?

This Campagnolo chain is not incompatible with Shimano 9 speed cassettes in general: I've gone through a couple of these, and had overall good experience. I cannot remember when I changed to the last pair, but it's been more than one year - that means at least 11000 km, much of it commuting under all weather conditions with lots of acceleration and partially steep, fast ascension + some tours over some of the Swiss alps passes.

Comment: Why are you running a Campy chain with Shimano cassettes? What kind of drivetrain are you running?

Comment: because of the longevity of the chain. I used some Shimano, and, IIRC KMC. I was really underwhelmed by the Shimano after it was done after a couple of month, less so by the other one.

Comment: Alright, I was wrong about the slip over the sprocket, it was the little chainring that is causing problems. Probably it was doing OK with the lengthened old chain, the C9 has somewhat shorter elements than about every other chain. This plus maybe some mechanical differences, as @graeme pointed out

Comment: So you have a Campy crankset, Shimano cassette and Campy chain or what? If you're running Shimano/Sram crankset+cassette you should use a Shimano/SRAM/KMC/Wipperman chain. And change your chain+cassette more often.

Comment: Short of the chain my drivetrain is a mix of Shimano stuff. Care to explain why you basically insist on not-Campa-chains for Shimano/SRAM? AFAIK all chains have the same pitch and roller size, and widths are compatible.

I change chain when it exceeds 256 mm. This one was a bit more (256.3mm) because I awaited end of winter. Cassette goes whenever it looks or feels bad. I did maintenance only now because I damaged the fork and got to repair that only now.

Comment: A Campy chain costs about 7 times as much as a SRAM chain in the US. It does look like they're compatible in this case, surprisingly (Campy doesn't play nice most of the time).

Comment: I get them for 23€ from Germany, which is not nearly 7 times any other chain, other completely plated chains cost 20-30€. Here in Switzerland you pay an extra factor of 2-3 for most bike-related stuff compared to Germany.

Answer (score 2):

Might be a spec change by Shimano - I know that there is no change to the Campag chain. As they are not designed to be compatible, if Shimano *have* changed something they will have done so only referencing their own 9s HG type chain which is slightly narrower than Campagnolo's.

The other things to look at are a stiif link or a chain rivet protruding slightly at the join.

If it's once per crank rev (rather than once per full chain rev) it would be more likely to be related to the rings - if you are doing 11000km per chain / cassette I'd guess the rings might be getting pretty tired unless you are changing once every couple of chains - depends whose rings, riding conditions etc ...

Comment: 11000 km for a chain is absurd. 11000 km for a cassette is not as absurd, but still pretty absurd.

Comment: I use these chains so that I don't have to change three times per year as I had to with Shimanos...