# Choosing a new chain

Tags: chain

I am going to buy a new chain for my bike, and read the answers for this question: [Is the durability of more expensive chains better than cheaper ones?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/31860/advantage-of-expensive-chains)

The accepted answer said, that there is no difference between inexpensive and expensive chains.

Then I googled and found [this post](http://www.bicycleslondon.co.uk/shimano-vs-kmc-bicycle-chains/) where the author says, that Shimano chains are bad, and KMC - good. There is a difference in price:

1. [Cheap Chinese chain 116 links](http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-9-Speed-CN-HG73-116-Links-HG-73-Bike-Bicycle-Chain-For-SHIMANO-Deore-LX-105/141379486975) - $9.54 + free shipping
2. [KMC X9 chain 112 links](http://www.ebay.com/itm/mr-ride-KMC-X9-Silver-9-Speed-112-link-road-mtb-bike-for-Shimano-/231510941409) - $14.89 + $4.04 shipping = $18.93
3. [KMC X9 chain 116 links](http://www.ebay.com/itm/KMC-X9-Vivid-Bike-Chain-Pink-9-Speed-116-Link-Campagnolo-Shimano-SRAM-New-/252023728917) - $27.46 + $7.37 shipping = $34.83

Questions:

1. Can I trust to the post author, suggesting to buy KMC chains?
2. Why the 2-nd chain has only 112 link, while normally there are 116 for a 9 speed bike? I counted number of links in my current chain, and there are 104.
3. Is the 3-rd chain better then the 2-nd? Seems to be the same model.

Comment: Some bikes need the longer chain.  And which chain you pick in part depends on which type of joining method you want.  I prefer the SRAM links, some prefer the KMC links, some prefer the Shimano links.  The Chinese chain likely comes with nothing, expecting you to use the "old fashioned" technique.

Comment: As the person that wrote the answer about inexpensive/expensive chains, I was only thinking of chains within a specific manufacturer. i.e. Basic $20 SRAM chains vs the $80 ones. There is a difference between brands.

Comment: I would advise against buying cheap no-name or copy stuff from China (in general, not just chains) since something you *could* end up with factory rejected chains that they try to sell you off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This is the best test of chain wear I know of](http://radreise-forum.de/topics/308644): it's in german, but the graph should speak for itself. His comment: "Chains were used under subjectively similar conditions - with exception of SRAM PC69 which, in nice conditions, lives for 1500-1800km"

Personally I think I rode unknown KMC, Shimano (probably HG-53), and afer having stumbled upon said findings, the Record C9. Different chains definitely have different lifetimes (and failure modes: some tend to tear, some lengthen quickly thus unusable). I have very good experience with C9, however, it is harder to mount (no missing link), and apparently it is incompatible with some slightly worn chainrings, but I'm not sure there. I posted a question on that problem [here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/31044/campagnolo-record-c9-shimano-cs-hg200-9-incompatibility). IIRC, with me, Shimano chains wore fastest, KMC were somewhat better, maybe in the 2000-4000km range. The C9 lives some 10000 km for me. However, you seem to be located in the USA, apparently it's quite expensive there.

With cheap no-name chains I'd guess it depends on your luck. A bad quality chain will wear maybe in a couple 100km, and may tear.

Comment: I bought Campagnolo C9. 10 000 km is worth the money.

Comment: I have similar experience with SRAM chains.  I actually had one break on me in two places once.  You may also look at Whipperman which is another spendy but decent chain company.

Comment: If someone is looking for the missing image from the forum it seems it is this one: https://www.flickr.com/photos/denmes/9560857109/